# How to return multiple values?

Tags: java

Is it possible to return two or more values from a method to main in Java? If so, how it is possible and if not how can we do?

Comment: Return array, list, set, map or your custom object containing multiple values. I have seen this same question somewhere.... let me find that. There are multiple questions on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=return+multiple+values+in+java%3F

Comment: Maybe too late, but Just use java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleIEntry. Reusable, everywher since 1.6

Comment: If you are on Java 14+, it is better in general to use a Java Record instead of a SimpleEntry for representing a pair of values.

Answer (score 93):

You can return an object of a Class in Java.

If you are returning more than 1 value that are related, then it makes sense to encapsulate them into a class and then return an object of that class.

If you want to return unrelated values, then you can use Java's built-in container classes like Map, List, Set etc. Check the [java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) package's JavaDoc for more details.

Comment: I would add one more point to this - keep your returned object immutable (best initialize it in a constructor and keep your fields final)

Comment: You can return an object , but if you have so many return objects in your program it makes the source code complicated. for things that are returned from a method once-of-its-kind-it-the-program better to have Tuples. like c#. darling c# its a great language

Comment: I guess there should be C# `out` or `ref` parameter equivalent in Java, otherwise I will need to create class even for returning two variables and for each function returning multiple values. If we follow this, then there will be a class for every function returning multiple values. Though using `Map` feels better approach now.

Comment: I would use a map or set for keeping it simple :)

Comment: I think you mean `If you are returning more than 1 value that are un-related` and vice versa

Comment: Returning maps, lists or sets (to avoid returning a DTO) IMHO is an antipattern.

Answer (score 42):

You can do something like this:

```
public class Example
{
    public String name;
    public String location;

    public String[] getExample()
    {
        String ar[] = new String[2];
        ar[0]= name;
        ar[1] =  location;
        return ar; //returning two values at once
    }
}
```

Comment: How performance efficient is this?

Answer (score 39):

You can only return one value, but it can be an object that has multiple fields - ie a "value object". Eg

```
public class MyResult {
    int returnCode;
    String errorMessage;
    // etc
}

public MyResult someMethod() {
    // impl here
}
```