# Java how to return two variables?

Tags: java, return

after c++ i am trying to learn some java, and i have a question about the code i have been working on. I am working on a Fraction class and i got stuck in reduce section. Since the method did not let me to return both "num" and "den", I had to return "n" 
This is my method

```
public double reduce() {
    int n = num;
    int d = den;

    while (d != 0) {
        int t = d;
        d = n % d;
        n = t;
    }
    int gcd = n;

    num /= gcd; //num = num / greatestCommonDivisor
    den /= gcd; //den = den / greatestCommonDivisor
    return n;
}
```

I am trying to do "return num, den;" however it does not let me.

and this is what i get

```
to reduced test for  100/2 is 2.0
to reduced test for  6/2 is 2.0
```

when i run

```
System.out.println("to reduced test for  " + f4.toString() + " is " + f4.reduce());
System.out.println("to reduced test for  " + f6.toString() + " is " +f6.reduce());
```

Why do i get the 2 when when i am supposed to get 50/1 and 3/1 ? If the IDE let me return num and den at the same time, would that have fixed it?

Thanks

Comment: This is a n-times duplicate, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557716/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-java or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609269/best-practice-for-returning-multiple-values-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has no native way of doing this, you only can return one **Object** or primitive. This leaves you two options:

- Return an array with length 2.

  ```
  public int[] reduce()
  {
      ...
      return new int[]{num, den};
  }
  ```
- Return an object of a wrapper class containing the two numbers.

  ```
  public Fraction reduce()
  {
      ...
      return new Fraction(num, den);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much, return new Fraction(num, den) did the trick (=

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `reduce` method is modifying the object.  It's unclear what exactly you want to return.  If you want the fraction to return itself, then `return this;`, with the method returning a `Fraction` in the declaration.