# How to pass two parameter from 1 class to another in a function?

Tags: java, android

This is one of the class where i assign data to the item and it return one parameter back to the other class. How should i write it to return two parameter instead? For this case it return final price, how should i write it to return final price and subtotal as well?

```
public static String Final_Price = " ";
public static String subtotal = " ";
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
Final_Price = co.price;
subtotal = co.subtotal;
return Final_Price;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){

   String search = Final_Price;
    ((ReceiptActivity)activity).get_data(search);
}
```

This is the receipt activity where there is a function to get the data i pass.

```
public void get_data (String c)
{
shippingfeeTextView.setText("Shipping fee: " + c);
}
```

Comment: You can create your own Model and then can set the value of two three or as many as you want attributes and then can simply pass that object

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557716/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-java

Comment: return String array `String[]` with size 2.

Comment: how to write it with size 2?

Comment: replce Co with String in third parameter of asynctask ,return co. then you get both price and subtotal as result in onPostExecte

Comment: check my answer.. just clarify you want to pass 2 params to a method or return 2 params.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only two parameters, you can use `Pair`. Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom object like this

```
public class Result{
        public String finalPrice, subTotoal;

    public Result(String st, String fp) {
        this.subTotal= st;
        this.finalPrice= fp;
    }

}
```

Then you can return Result object instead

```
Result res = new Result (x, y);
return res
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return it as array, object or you can create a model and pass the model as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two return values you want are the same data type, it's best not to over think things.
Just return a simple array:

```
double[] finalPrice = new double[2];
    finalPrice[0] = co.price;
    finalPrice[1] = co.subtotal;
    return finalPrice;
```

or if you need to keep it a string:

```
String[] finalPrice = new String[2];
    finalPrice[0] = ""+co.price;
    finalPrice[1] = ""+co.subtotal;
    return finalPrice;
```

This would be the simplest and most effective way to handle returning multiple values. 
To use your array is simple as well:

```
    public void get_data (String[] c)
{
shippingfeeTextView.setText("Shipping fee: " + c[0]+"subtotal: "+c[1]);
}
```

If the values are different data types, just create an encapsulated data class with the appropriate fields, getters / setters, and return it's constructor:

```
return new CustomContainer(myDouble, anInteger);
```

Your get method would then look something like this:

```
public void get_data (CustomContainer c)
{
shippingfeeTextView.setText("Shipping fee: " + c.getSalePrice()+"subtotal:   "+c.getSubTotal());
}
```